# Can OMP_WAIT_POLICY/GOMP_SPINCOUNT environment variable be set using C++ API or any solution to avoid high CPU issues with OpenMP default settings?

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to enable OpenMP Support to true in the application via Visual Studio 2019 and ended up with high CPU issues with the code below:

```
omp_set_dynamic(0);
omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());
#pragma omp parallel for
//CPU intensive operation
```

I am able to fix this high CPU issues by setting the system environment variable `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` to `PASSIVE` or `GOMP_SPINCOUNT` to `0`.

But, the request here is to set this variable in runtime using something like `omp_set_wait_policy("passive")`.
As far as I have read through the OpenMP documentation, I don't see any such runtime API available.

Is there any alternative solution to avoid this issue?

Comment: This variable modify the `wait-policy-var` which cannot be set using a user-defined function regarding the OpenMP 5.0 specification (section 2.5.3). Note that setting things like the number of threads manually is not generally considered as a good practice. It is frequent for the user to want to control this externally because the choice is generally platform-dependent and developers often have no control of the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

One can set environment variables immediately from C code before any call to OpenMP library, using POSIX `putenv` function [existing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv?view=msvc-170) in Visual Studio as well.

For example, set it in the very beginning of your `main()` function:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    putenv( "OMP_WAIT_POLICY=PASSIVE" );
    ...
```